# how to add a UILabel in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel

i have big Image in my app. i create it dynamically and i want to add a UILabel on this image:

```
UIImageView *thumbnailImage;
thumbnailImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xImage, yImage, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblTitle.text = @"SomeText"; 
lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(xTitle, yTitle , titleWidth ,titleHeight);
[thumbnailImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
thumbnailImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
[thumbnailImage addSubview:lblTitle];
```

but the `[thumbnailImage addSubview:UILabel];` code does not work.

any one have any idea?

Comment: where do you set the label's text ? an empty label will not be shown unless you specify a non transparent background color

Comment: you are adding UILabel instead of lblTitle

Comment: UILabel and set a text for lable was typing misstake. i edit them.

Comment: is the frame for the label inside the image view? view frames are in the coordinates of their superviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to add some text on bottom of picture like news article.

so I solve it with below code, if any one have a better idea please share it.

```
UIImageView *thumbnailImage;
thumbnailImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xImage, yImage, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xImage,imageHeight - titleHeight , titleWidth , titleHeight )];
UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xTitle, yTitle , titleWidth ,titleHeight)];
titleView.alpha = 0.3;
[thumbnailImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
thumbnailImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:thumbnailImage];
[self.view addSubview:titleView];
lblTitle.textLabel.text = @"SomeText";
```

first I use below line  of Code:

```
 [titleView addSubview:lblTitle]
```

but the alpha of `titleView` impact `lblTitle` and made it transparent. so after delete this line `lblTitle` Text appear clear and bright.

Answer (score 0):

thumbnailImage is a UIView, so you can add subviews to it.instead of writing the line

`[thumbnailImage addSubview:UILabel];`

edit it with the following ::

```
[thumbnailImage addSubview:lblTitle];
```

This will work . :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to initialize the label with it's frame.

You should add a text to the label

You should add the `UILabel` object (`lblTitle`) to the imageview instead of the `UILabel` type.

With these corrections, your code should look like this:

```
UIImageView *thumbnailImage;
thumbnailImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xImage, yImage, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
[thumbnailImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
thumbnailImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xTitle, yTitle , titleWidth ,titleHeight)];
lblTitle.textLabel.text = @"Your text";
[thumbnailImage addSubview:lblTitle];
```

Comment: i made some correction in my Code. in fact i want to add some text in a transparent area in bottom of picture like news article.